# JS triggered overflow hidden not resizing child elements width

Tags: javascript, css

I have added a JS binder to remove the scroll-bar from a div and I was able to implement that.

Not sure how to explain my problem, but width of child elements is not re-sizing once I set `overflow: hidden`.

Have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwRmY/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem complete. You have only included code for setting overflow to hidden. Instead I would've expected code for the bit that isn't working (the resize) as well.

Comment: Also, there is just 1 child element, namely the header. The others are text nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `<div class="header"` inside `<div class="box"`. You need to restructure the html and need to modify header css with some JQuery changes like below (please find [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwRmY/33/) for same)

**CSS**

```
.header {
    background-color:red;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="header">
        Testing
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    This is a random text <br> 
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#hide-overflow").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".box").css("overflow","hidden");
        $(".box").css("height","100%");
    } else {
        $(".box").css("overflow", "auto");
        $(".box").css("height","100px");
    }
})
```

Here I have made header seperate with same width as box div i.e. `100px`. In JQuery, I am setting height to `100%` for no scroll bar and resetting it to `100px` for scroll.

Answer (score 0):

From the question as I understand..You want to decrease the size of the box..

You can set it from the jquery itself..

```
$("#hide-overflow").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".box").css({overflow: "hidden"});
        $(".box").css({height: "20px"});
    } else {
        $(".box").css("overflow", "auto");
        $(".box").css({height: "100px"});
    }
})
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwRmY/8/)...